# How to add in-app advertising?

Tags: software-center, application-development, programming

I'd like to code something cool for the ubuntu software center.
I'll release my app for free, but I'd like to add some in-app advertising.

how can I do that?

Thanks to all developers here around ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any kind of Advertising SDK for Ubuntu. What you can try doing is creating a WebView widget using whatever interface toolkit you're using to build your app and embed a Google AdSense widget in it.